# Sum of countif across certain rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a form that in which people in various groups select from the same options across multiple questions. The data comes to excel in the format:

```
    A        B        C        D        E
1 Group 1 Option A Option C Option B Option C
2 Group 2 Option B Option A Option C Option A
3 Group 1 Option C Option B Option A Option B
4 Group 3 Option B Option B Option C Option C
5 Group 2 Option A Option A Option B Option C
```

How can I count the number of people in each group that selected each option? I can use the the countif and the sumif functions separately but I'm wondering if there's a way to combine those two function into one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT - for example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="Group 1")*(B1:E5="Option A"))
```

if the Option can be part of a cell, rather than the entire cell contents, and delimited by semicolons, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="Group 1")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";Option A;",";"&B1:E5&";"))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I unfortunately simplified the problem when asking (and your method works perfectly in this simplified version!) but each person can actually pick multiple options for each question so the data in each column is actually in the format "Option A;Option B;Option D" and so on. I thought I'd be able to use a wildcard,  * & Option A & *, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @CFERG I've amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: You champion! Thank you so much!